# Removing footers of CSV files in R

Tags: r, footer

I am trying to remove footers of some CSV files that have different lengths, after importing to R. In all the files, footers start with the cell having: "Footnotes:". As a simple example of the data, if the column names are A, B and C, I want to keep the first row (1,2,3) and remove the other two rows: "Footnotes:" and "Blah Blah Blah"

```
 A             B      C
 1             2      3
 Footnotes:
 Blah         Blah   Blah
```

I don't know why grep doesn't do the job:

```
df <- read.table("df.csv", header = TRUE,sep = ",", 
quote = "\"",dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "")
  if(length(grep("Footnotes:",df))>0){
    df<-df[-c(grep("Footnotes:",df):length(df))]
  }
```

Here is a link to a simple version of the CSV file: [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15CMfqlynHAuHBo36M2m50O-WS-DVCtV-/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks

Comment: "footer" is not a helpful tag, but the used programming language would be..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that removes every row after (and including) footer:

```
removeFooter <- function(df) {
    df[cumsum(grepl("Footnotes", df$A)) < 1,]
}
```

`grepl` returns a logical vector the same length as the number of rows of `df` with a single `TRUE` in the row containing "Footnotes". `cumsum` coerces the logical vector into a numeric vector of zeros and ones and returns a running total. All rows up to the "Footnotes" are zeros, and all after are ones.

Answer (score 0):

You're over-complicating with the `if` statement and `length` bits. We find the row number of the first row containing "Footnotes", subtract one, and subset.

```
df2 <- df[1:min(grep("Footnotes",df$A)) -1, ]
```